# Displaying sections from pre-checked options

Tags: javascript, performance, jquery, dom

First off, not the greatest with jQuery but know enough to get by. I have a custom script for our WordPress site that ties in with a main plugin we use. I have a JSFiddle that gives the gist of what it does as well as the staging site. My main goal right now is to improve upon the code. The main thing is trim the fat and reduce the wait for it to properly display the page.

This checks if one of the options are pre-checked first. If so, display the correct section and hide the rest. The second is when changing options to do the same but also uncheck any options that could have been selected under the "Stains" section.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    // Create Variables
    var stains = $(".stains-container");
    var radio_buttons = $("input[name='tmcp_radio_0'], input.wood-class");

    // Check if Oak is checked
    var oak_checked         = $(":radio[value^=Oak_], :radio[value*=Oak_], :radio[value^=Barnwood_]").is(":checked");
    var $oakchecked         = $("input.b-maple-stains, input.cherry-stains, input.qswo-stains, input.h-maple-stains, input.hickory-stains, input.walnut-stains");
    var $oakactive          = $(".b-maple-stains-div li, .cherry-stains-div li, .qswo-stains-div li, .h-maple-stains-div li, .hickory-stains-div li, .walnut-stains-div li");
    var $oakactivehide      = $(".b-maple-stains-div, .cherry-stains-div, .qswo-stains-div, .h-maple-stains-div, .hickory-stains-div, .walnut-stains-div");
    // Check if B. Maple is checked
    var bmaple_checked      = $(":radio[value^=Brown], :radio[value^=Wormy]").is(":checked");
    var $bmaplechecked      = $("input.oak-stains, input.cherry-stains, input.qswo-stains, input.h-maple-stains, input.hickory-stains, input.walnut-stains");
    var $bmapleactive       = $(".oak-stains-div li, .cherry-stains-div li, .qswo-stains-div li, .h-maple-stains-div li, .hickory-stains-div li, .walnut-stains-div li");
    var $bmapleactivehide   = $(".oak-stains-div, .cherry-stains-div, .qswo-stains-div, .h-maple-stains-div, .hickory-stains-div, .walnut-stains-div");
    // Check if Cherry is checked
    var cherry_checked      = $(":radio[value^=Cherry_], :radio[value*=Cherry_]").is(":checked");
    var $cherrychecked      = $("input.oak-stains, input.b-maple-stains, input.qswo-stains, input.h-maple-stains, input.hickory-stains, input.walnut-stains");
    var $cherryactive       = $(".oak-stains-div li, .b-maple-stains-div li, .qswo-stains-div li, .h-maple-stains-div li, .hickory-stains-div li, .walnut-stains-div li");
    var $cherryactivehide   = $(".oak-stains-div, .b-maple-stains-div, .qswo-stains-div, .h-maple-stains-div, .hickory-stains-div, .walnut-stains-div");
    // Check if QSWO is checked
    var qswo_checked        = $(":radio[value^=Quartersawn]").is(":checked");
    var $qswochecked        = $("input.oak-stains, input.b-maple-stains, input.cherry-stains, input.h-maple-stains, input.hickory-stains, input.walnut-stains");
    var $qswoactive         = $(".oak-stains-div li, .b-maple-stains-div li, .cherry-stains-div li, .h-maple-stains-div li, .hickory-stains-div li, .walnut-stains-div li");
    var $qswoactivehide     = $(".oak-stains-div, .b-maple-stains-div, .cherry-stains-div, .h-maple-stains-div, .hickory-stains-div, .walnut-stains-div");
    // Check if H. Maple is checked
    var hmaple_checked      = $(":radio[value^=Hard], :radio[value*=Hard]").is(":checked");
    var $hmaplechecked      = $("input.oak-stains, input.b-maple-stains, input.cherry-stains, input.qswo-stains, input.hickory-stains, input.walnut-stains");
    var $hmapleactive       = $(".oak-stains-div li, .b-maple-stains-div li, .cherry-stains-div li, .qswo-stains-div li, .hickory-stains-div li, .walnut-stains-div li");
    var $hmapleactivehide   = $(".oak-stains-div, .b-maple-stains-div, .qswo-stains-div, .cherry-stains-div, .hickory-stains-div, .walnut-stains-div");
    // Check if Hickory is checked
    var hickory_checked     = $(":radio[value^=Hickory_], :radio[value*=Hickory_]").is(":checked");
    var $hickorychecked     = $("input.oak-stains, input.b-maple-stains, input.cherry-stains, input.qswo-stains, input.h-maple-stains, input.walnut-stains");
    var $hickoryactive      = $(".oak-stains-div li, .b-maple-stains-div li, .cherry-stains-div li, .qswo-stains-div li, .h-maple-stains-div li, .walnut-stains-div li");
    var $hickoryactivehide  = $(".oak-stains-div, .b-maple-stains-div, .qswo-stains-div, .h-maple-stains-div, .cherry-stains-div, .walnut-stains-div");
    // Check if Walnut is checked
    var walnut_checked     = $(":radio[value^=Walnut_], :radio[value*=Walnut_]").is(":checked");
    var $walnutchecked     = $("input.oak-stains, input.b-maple-stains, input.cherry-stains, input.qswo-stains, input.h-maple-stains, input.hickory-stains");
    var $walnutactive      = $(".oak-stains-div li, .b-maple-stains-div li, .cherry-stains-div li, .qswo-stains-div li, .h-maple-stains-div li, .hickory-stains-div li");
    var $walnutactivehide  = $(".oak-stains-div, .b-maple-stains-div, .qswo-stains-div, .h-maple-stains-div, .cherry-stains-div, .hickory-stains-div");

    // Hide stains unless a wood is chosen
    if(oak_checked) {
        $(".oak-stains-div").show();
        $oakactivehide.hide();
        $oakchecked.prop('checked', false);
        $oakactive.removeClass( "tc-active" );
    } else if(bmaple_checked) {
        $(".b-maple-stains-div").show();
        $bmapleactivehide.hide();
        $bmaplechecked.prop('checked', false);
        $bmapleactive.removeClass( "tc-active" );
    } else if(cherry_checked) {
        $(".cherry-stains-div").show();
        $cherryactivehide.hide();
        $cherrychecked.prop('checked', false);
        $cherryactive.removeClass( "tc-active" );
    } else if(qswo_checked) {
        $(".qswo-stains-div").show();
        $qswoactivehide.hide();
        $qswochecked.prop('checked', false);
        $qswoactive.removeClass( "tc-active" );
    } else if(hmaple_checked) {
        $(".h-maple-stains-div").show();
        $hmapleactivehide.hide();
        $hmaplechecked.prop('checked', false);
        $hmapleactive.removeClass( "tc-active" );
    } else if(hickory_checked) {
        $(".hickory-stains-div").show();
        $hickoryactivehide.hide();
        $hickorychecked.prop('checked', false);
        $hickoryactive.removeClass( "tc-active" );
    } else if(walnut_checked) {
        $(".walnut-stains-div").show();
        $walnutactivehide.hide();
        $walnutchecked.prop('checked', false);
        $walnutactive.removeClass( "tc-active" );
    } else if(radio_buttons.is(":not(:checked)")) {
        $(".stains-container").hide();
    } 

    // Check if Oak is selected or pre-selected
    radio_buttons.on('change', function(e) {
      var oakRegExp = /^Oak_\d$/;
      var reclaimedOakRegExp = /^Reclaimed Oak_\d$/;
      var barnwoodOakRegExp = /^Reclaimed Barnwood_\d$/;
      var rstHckOakRegExp = /^Rustic Hickory Twigs and Oak_\d$/;

      if (oakRegExp.test(e.target.value) || reclaimedOakRegExp.test(e.target.value) || barnwoodOakRegExp.test(e.target.value) || rstHckOakRegExp.test(e.target.value)) {
        stains.show();
        $(".oak-stains-div").show();
        $oakchecked.prop('checked', false);
        $oakactive.removeClass("tc-active");
      } else {
        $(".oak-stains-div").hide();
      }
    });

    // Check if B. Maple is selected or pre-selected
    radio_buttons.on('change', function(e) {
      var brownMapleRegExp = /^Brown Maple_\d$/;
      var wormyMapleRegExp = /^Wormy Maple_\d$/;

      if (brownMapleRegExp.test(e.target.value) || wormyMapleRegExp.test(e.target.value)) {
        stains.show();
        $(".b-maple-stains-div").show();
        $bmaplechecked.prop('checked', false);
        $bmapleactive.removeClass("tc-active");
      } else {
        $(".b-maple-stains-div").hide();
      }
    });

    // Check if Cherry is selected or pre-selected
    radio_buttons.on('change', function(e) {
      var cherryRegExp = /^Cherry_\d$/;
      var rusticCherryRegExp = /^Rustic Cherry_\d$/;
      var rusticHickoryCherryRegExp = /^Rustic Hickory Twigs and Cherry_\d$/;

      if (cherryRegExp.test(e.target.value) || rusticCherryRegExp.test(e.target.value) || rusticHickoryCherryRegExp.test(e.target.value)) {
        stains.show();
        $(".cherry-stains-div").show();
        $cherrychecked.prop('checked', false);
        $cherryactive.removeClass( "tc-active" );
      } else {
        $(".cherry-stains-div").hide();
      }
    });

    // Check if QSWO is selected or pre-selected
    radio_buttons.on('change', function(e) {
      var qswoRegExp = /^Quartersawn White Oak_\d$/;

      if (qswoRegExp.test(e.target.value)) {
        stains.show();
        $(".qswo-stains-div").show();
        $qswochecked.prop('checked', false);
        $qswoactive.removeClass( "tc-active" );
      } else {
        $(".qswo-stains-div").hide();
      }
    });

    // Check if Hard Maple is selected or pre-selected
    radio_buttons.on('change', function(e) {
      var hMapleRegExp = /^Hard Maple_\d$/;
      var rusticHickoryhMapleRegExp = /^Rustic Hickory Twigs and Hard Maple_\d$/;

      if (hMapleRegExp.test(e.target.value) || rusticHickoryhMapleRegExp.test(e.target.value)) {
        stains.show();
        $(".h-maple-stains-div").show();
        $hmaplechecked.prop('checked', false);
        $hmapleactive.removeClass( "tc-active" );
      } else {
        $(".h-maple-stains-div").hide();
      }
    });

    // Check if Hickory is selected or pre-selected
    radio_buttons.on('change', function(e) {
      var hickoryRegExp = /^Hickory_\d$/;
      var rusticHickoryTwigsHickoryRegExp = /^Rustic Hickory Twigs and Hickory_\d$/;

      if (hickoryRegExp.test(e.target.value) || rusticHickoryTwigsHickoryRegExp.test(e.target.value)) {
        stains.show();
        $(".hickory-stains-div").show();
        $hickorychecked.prop('checked', false);
        $hickoryactive.removeClass( "tc-active" );
      } else {
        $(".hickory-stains-div").hide();
      }
    });

    // Check if Walnut is selected or pre-selected
    radio_buttons.on('change', function(e) {
      var walnutRegExp = /^Walnut_\d$/;
      var rusticWalnutRegExp = /^Rustic Walnut_\d$/;

      if (walnutRegExp.test(e.target.value) || rusticWalnutRegExp.test(e.target.value)) {
        stains.show();
        $(".walnut-stains-div").show();
        $walnutchecked.prop('checked', false);
        $walnutactive.removeClass( "tc-active" );
      } else {
        $(".walnut-stains-div").hide();
      }
    });
});
```

The HTML is ripped off the staging site so it's very unreadable so it's best I just drop the JSFiddle link [here](https://jsfiddle.net/amishdirect/h94c7rsw/). If anyone has any suggestions on trimming some fat I would so very much appreciate it. Or if you have any suggestions on reducing the page time (Waiting (TTFB)). I've tried to defer and/or async the JS and it doesn't seem to improve anything.

[Staging site](https://amishdirectfurniture-staging.g3wenplb-liquidwebsites.com/shop/dining/table/trestle-table/abilene-dining-table/)

Comment: If you have problems with ttfb then fe js Is not the core of it. Its on backend. Anyway try narrowing CSS selectors to only select under a Common ancestor which you already revealed. Dont lookup the entire document again And again.

Comment: Unfortunately since I have to work around the plugin and a lot of it is generated this is the best way for me to do it. I am trying to find a better work around for how it finds if a button is checked or not.

Comment: Two things would be very helpful: An explanation on what this script actually does and the HTML it works on.

Comment: I added a description. The staging site demonstrates the actual live set up. The JSFiddle just narrows down the exact portion I am trying to clean up.